# How to deploy app service with pipeline variables as an artifact to be downloaded?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-deployment

I have an app service which is deployed to Azure WebApp for testing (this works just fine), but since this eventually shall be deployed to an on-premises solution I need to create a deployment package that I can download from either Azure Portal or from DevOps.

So far I have tried creating a Releases pipeline which picks up the build artifact and use the AzureBlob File Copy task to copy the artifact from DevOps to a storage account in Azure. The problem I have now is the the File Copy task does not set the varialbes I have in the Variable groups into the appsettings.json file (such as DbConnection and port settings).

What would be the best way to create a deployment package (with updated appsettings.json values) to be available for download either from Azure Portal or DevOps, without the need to create a dedicated app service in Azure for the deployment?

This is the steps I have at the moment, but as mentioned the configuration property for setting the varialbes are not available for the AzureBlob File Copy:
[Pipeline Tasks and Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoUDW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to deploy app service with pipeline variables as an artifact to be downloaded?

You could try to use the task [File transform (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic) to update the `appsettings.json` file with the value in the variable groups:

[image]

Then we could use the Azure File Copy task to copy the artifact from DevOps to a storage account in Azure.

**Note:** The **Source** of the Azure File Copy task should be use the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` instead of select the repo file:

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's the one. Thank you so much :)

Comment: So I tried this solution now for the Release pipeline:
1. Copy Files: Copy the artifact to a new location
2. File Transform: On the copied artifact
3. Universal publish: Publish the new artifact to project feed
So I get the new artifacts (one for on premises test and one for release) in the feed on the DevOps site, but not sure if this is the best solution though.

Comment: @RuneØnvikLorentzen, This is a production process selection problem. It must be combined with your actual project requirements to determine whether it is the best choice, so I cannot give you a positive reply directly. But at least for now it is working.